# Inform web service If app is closed

Tags: php, android, web-services, session, ping

I have Implemented webservice which is consumed by android application, 
this web service is used for Login and signup from Android app.

After Login from android App I want to check time to time that android user is still logged in,

**what I tried?**

I used **countdowntimer** & **asynctask** to send request to web service as one ping type message , it is sent periodically , but how can I manage webservice to check if it is not sent after some time. SO that I can end session if I don't receive that ping from server side. web service is Built in PHP ,symfony

I want this to Implement because one may close services of app so that I have to logout session from web service Immediately

what can I do at android side. **Is there is any alternative solution to do this?**

Comment: y r u sendng the session time again and again to service ..just do that in client side and when the session times out in client side then  send request to server side

Comment: @Monika My app give access to internet by logging in to wifi network, so if anyone kill service or app I want to check from server side that he have done that , so I can logout him  to avoid miss use

Comment: @Monika problem is that i want to close his Internet connection from web service if he kills app services and process, thats why I can't send request from client side

Comment: yes but that can be tracked from android side as well ...that will make ur issue more easy

Comment: @Monika so how the web service will get Informed if someone kills app from : 
 Application> Manage Application > Stop App

Comment: u can log the value in shared pref and in case the application stop also then the last value will persist in shared pref

Answer (score 1):

you can try one thing,

when the application in your device is closed than you should fire one webservice to tell your webapp that the application is closed,

and you can save a flag value in your web database.

And you just have to check the flag if it is on or off to fire your desired webservice.. :)

Comment: how he will get app close event ?

Comment: he don't need to get the app close event, just fire the webservice when the close button is pushed.

Comment: that close button is in androids settings i.e Settings->Applications->Manage Application->App_name->Force stop, can we get that close button event

Comment: and you can also use a `timer()` `function` in you application to fire a `webservice` that will continuesly check wether app is running or not. just like whatsapp.
and when that webservice stops so you can come to know that the app is closed. :)

Comment: @NishantSolanki hmmm. that looks like an option, so in web service I have to check that I am receiving something continuously from app, if I stop receiving that from app that means app is closed

Comment: @user2934866 yeah. you got it.. :)

Comment: @user2934866 if you like my answer please +1 and chose it as correct :)

Comment: added more appropriate changes to answer according to some android concepts so that I can accept it  @NishantSolanki